# Error:Unknown type name'virtual' and Expected member name or ; after declaration specifers

Tags: c++

So I'm using xcode and for some reason I can't declare any virtual function. This is my code in my .h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; 

class monkey{
public:
virtual void name(int a);//this is where the error occurs saying unknown type name
};
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure you're not compiling C?

Comment: I think you're compiling in Objective-C.

Comment: @AndyProwl C would fail at `class`. Or with the templates in `<iostream>`.

Comment: @Barry: Yeah, good point. It must be Objective-C then, as hinted by 0x :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 I dont think im compiling in objective c because i have a cpp file

Comment: @Darraptor It's still a text file, and can be parsed differently irrespective of its file extension. We don't usually see C++ compiler errors like that. Create a new project but remember to choose C++ as the language.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I made a new project in C++ but I still got the same error. I know this is a C++ file because its a cpp and I def clicked on c++

Comment: @Darraptor Is this file the only project?

Comment: Make sure it is actually being compiled. Put some jibberish before the part giving the error and see if the compiler says anything.

Comment: @0x499602D2 i did but it wont compile still

Comment: @Darraptor Does it give a different error?

Comment: @0x499602D2 still the same one I dont know y i cant use virtual function in xcode

Comment: What happens if you comment out the bad code?

Comment: @0x499602D2 if i comment out the virtual part it works

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. My gut still tells me that somehow it's still being compiled as Objective-C.